# Visual Studio Binary Compatibility of C++ Libraries using STL

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Microsoft [claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160) binary compatibility between Visual Studio 2015,2017 and 2019.

> The runtime libraries and apps compiled by any of these versions of the compiler are binary-compatible.

How about static libraries (.lib files)?

I have my tiny C++ library composed of several C++ classes which make use of STL heavily. Header files of these classes are designed to be included in user applications, hence interface methods and data use STL containers. I deliver .lib,.dll and .h files to my users.

```
class MyClass {
public:
   MyClass(std::string person, std::vector<float> anArray);
   static std::vector<void*> getData();
}
```

If I would build my `mylibrary.lib` using VS2015, could it be used in VS2017?

Comment: It's documented as such. However there are significant benefits in moving to the newer compilers.

Comment: *"make use of STL heavily"* - That is inconsequential. What matters is the types you expose at the interface.

Comment: _"...If I would build my......"_ yes - however the computability is only forward compatibility (for details see the __Restrictions on binary compatibility__ section in the link you posted).  This means that you need to link with the most recent toolset you used to build any of your components.